# Design pattern to consume REST API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, design-patterns

I am making a DLL to consume a REST API in aspnetcore.

Ideally, I would like it to be accessed this way:

```
API api = new API(clientInfo);
api.Module.Entity.Action(params);
```

But I am struggling to make that a reality. I can't make anything static because more than 1 session might be instanced at the same time. I can't pass the session around except by reference otherwise session state(cookies etc.) might change in the copy. Is there a design pattern I should be using?

```
public class API
{
    private Session _session;
    public API(ClientInfo clientInfo)
    {
        _session = new Session(clientInfo);
    }
}
```

The session serves as middleware for the client, stores login data in case the client needs to repeat login, handles some errors/retries and exposes client methods.

```
public class Session
{
    private Client _client;
    private string _path;
    public Session(ClientInfo clientInfo)
    {
        _client= new Client(clientInfo);
        _path = clientInfo.Path;
    }
    public HttpResponseMessage Get(string name, string arguments = "")
    {
        return _client.Get(_path, name, arguments);
    }
    ...
}
```

The client actually performs the calls.

```
public class Client
{
    public HttpResponseMessage Get(string path, string endpointName, string arguments)
    {
        return GetClient().GetAsync(path + endpointName + arguments).Result;
    }
    private HttpClient GetClient(){...}
    ...
}
```

Comment: If you depend on Sessions you are already violating the stateless constraint of REST. Other than that, there are already quite a few REST Clients for C#, like [RestSharp](http://restsharp.org/). Might be worth looking into before you reinvent the wheel.

Comment: It's a secured api since it exposes business data. I can either perform a login every request (which severely affects request speed) or store session cookies. The dll could be used for large quantities of requests like importing partner data.

Comment: you could pass an Authentication-Token along with your Request. This wouldn't violate REST, since you wouldn't need a server-side Session any longer. However, this is getting Off-topic from your original answer, just wanted to inform you that what you're doing is technically not REST.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you are doing sync over async? Recommended is "async all the way". Also, just using `.Result` is shouting for trouble.

Answer (score 4):

Personally, I just build a simple client for my APIs, with methods corresponding to the endpoints the API has:

```
public class FooClient
{
    private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;

    public FooClient(HttpClient httpClient)
    {
        _httpClient = httpClient ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(httpClient));
    }

    public async Task<GetFooResult> Get(int id)
    {
        ...
    }

    // etc
}
```

The `HttpClient` dependency is provided by registering a typed client in Startup.cs:

```
services.AddHttpClient<FooClient>(c =>
{
    // configure client
});
```

And I add an `IServiceCollection` extension to encapsulate this and any other setup logic:

```
public static class IServiceCollectionExtensions
{
    public static IServiceCollection AddFooClient(this IServiceCollection services, string uri)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Then, in my Startup, I can simply do something like:

```
services.AddFooClient(Configuration.GetValue<string>("FooUri"));
```

This is extremely helpful for setting up automatic error handling, retry policies, etc. via Polly, as you can then set up all that configuration just once in the extension.

Now, getting to your issue of persisting things like auth tokens, you have a few possibilities. I tend to prefer persisting auth tokens as claims, in which case you can simply retrieve the claim and pass it into methods on your client that need it:

```
var foo = await _fooClient.Get(fooId, User.FindFirstValue("FooAuthToken"));
```

If you handle things that way, you can bind your client in any scope, including singleton.

An alternative approach would be to actually persist the auth token in your client, but this has to be done with care. You should definitely avoid using singleton scope, unless you're employing something like a `ConcurrentDictionary` and even then, ensuring that the right token is always used could be a bit gnarly.

Assuming you're using a request scope, you can store the token directly as an ivar or something, but you'd still need to persist it some place else beyond that, or you'd still need to re-auth for each request. If you were to store it in the session, for example, then you could do something like:

```
services.AddScoped<FooClient>(p =>
{
    var httpClientFactory = p.GetRequiredService<IHttpClientFactory>();
    var httpContextAccessor = p.GetRequiredService<IHttpContextAccessor>();

    var httpClient = httpClientFactory.Create("ClientName");
    var session = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session;

    var client = new FooClient(httpClient);
    client.SetAuthToken(session["FooAuthToken"]);
});
```

However, even then, I'd still say it's better to pass the auth token into the method than do any of this. It's more explicit about which actions require auth versus those that do not, and you always know exactly what's coming from where.

Answer (score 1):

One of your biggest problems will be the reuse of the HttpClient. This is a known problem for "pre-Core" days. Luckily, its been addressed and as of Net Core 2.1 we now have an HttpClientFactory which allows you to spin up as manage HttpClients as you need and they're handled for you as part of the framework.

https://www.stevejgordon.co.uk/introduction-to-httpclientfactory-aspnetcore

With this in mind, theres nothing stopping you from using DI to inject an IHttpClientFactory which will provide you with the necessary access to the pipeline you need. Other than that, its entirely up to you how you design the code which "manages" your access to the REST resources. Maybe some sort of Repository Pattern? (Purely guess work really without knowing your architecture etc)

Comment: A new HttpClient gets instanced every request. I try to avoid using DI in this case since that might not be how the next programmer wants to use the DLL. But yeah, it would be cleaner with DI.

Comment: If the class requires it, the class requires it. Therefore it should go as a dependency in the constructor. How you "inject" that dependency is up to you. But for promoting testable code its the preferred way of doing things.

Comment: OK, you edited the comment so that changes the context. The reason I pointed out the HttpClientFactory was to deal with that exact issue. Previously it would have been asking for trouble to inject an HttpClient. However, the HttpClientFactory is designed to specifically deal with that issue for you.

Comment: Thank you, I will use the information in the link you provided to optimize the way I use HttpClient.